# What the heck is the luraic language?

Tags: dnd-5e, languages

Our party is currently playing through Waterdeep: Dragon Heist (no spoilers, please!) and we're nearing the end of the campaign. The other night our party was discussing a teaching exchange of languages, and our party cleric (a human) mentioned that she could teach someone "luraic".

After a few minutes, we all came to the realisation that none of us had a clue what luraic is, or where it came from. It's on her character sheet, and it was picked when she originally selected the linguist feat. Another player remembers her picking it, and recognised the name, but couldn't recall where it came from.

We've since scoured language lists online but can't find any trace of this mystery language. We do know that at some point she transcribed her player sheet onto a new copy to make it neater, so one theory is that her handwriting was a bit sketchy and she copied something incorrectly, but none of us can find any languages that even read similarly to "luraic".

Is this a real D&D language? Does anyone have any theories as to what it might have been before a copying error? Any tips on how to handle this? For now she's removed it from her languages list and is considering alternatives that won't require any retcons.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Do you know what she used to create her character (e.g. D&D Beyond or another character builder online), or where she might have looked for lists of languages?

Comment: It would greatly help if you could narrow down the sourcebooks you guys used when you originally made the characters.

Comment: Do you have the original character sheet? Is the writing very horrible? If you replace the L with an A and replace IC with N you could get Auran.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The most likely candidate for a transcription error resulting in *luraic* is probably the *Luiric* language of Faerûnian halflings, who originally hail from the country of Luiren in the southeast.

Comment: That's possible but where would they have found that language? What book?

Comment: @Eternallord66 Any of a large number of Forgotten Realms books across multiple editions—Luiric is not exactly obscure in the Realms and most setting books mention it—but more likely, from the internet.

Comment: We think this is the most likely answer as we all remember halfling languages being mentioned when she was putting the character together.

Answer (score 8):

In the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide there is a sidebar for Human languages on page 112. Two of the languages listed is Turmic or Uluic. One of these could possibly be the culprit since the PC is human. Another thing I found that could be a possibility (unlikely) is maybe they were watching the streamer Luraic and they wrote it down without thinking.